# Which function can be used instead of get_result() when the Mysql query includes "SELECT * FROM..."?

Tags: php, android, mysql, webserver

I'm working on [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/) tutorial which everything is working perfect except this function :

```
public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $tasks = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    return $tasks;

}
```

The problem is because of the get_result() function because cpanel's php does not support this function, I have searched a lot in google and stackoverflow but there wasn't any answer that could help me, I just want a line that works same as get_result() function to replace it.

I would be very grateful for any help; Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what version of PHP is installed on your web-server?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : It's 5.4.45

Comment: also `mysqlnd` driver should be correctly installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get stack like this the same tutorial,before some days.

After some research,I found solution,explained below,It worked for me but not sure for you try.

```
public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
$query = "SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND     ut.user_id='". $user_id. "'";
 if ($result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query)) {
     return $result;
     mysqli_free_result($result);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Yes It's working, thanks for your response :) I used mysqli_query in this method and also in my DB_connection file , so It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

```
while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
    var_dump( $result );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I tried to print the $result in the json response in index file : $result=$db->getAllUserTasks($user_id);$response['res']=$result; echoRespnse(200, $response);     But the response was :" bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
{"res":null} "    actually this code is turning the $result to NULL.

Comment: The result variable used in the while loop gets row by row and you need to add the "current" $result to an array outside the loop. Like $outer_result_array.push($result); within the loop.

Comment: And maybe you need to $stmt->bind_result($varname,$varname_2,etc); I don't worked with mysqli so can't help any more than linking the tutorials above which should give you a working solution.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?  $stmt->execute();$tasks=array(); while($result = $stmt->fetch()){
            var_dump( $result );
  }
  array_push($tasks,$result);
        $stmt->close();
        return $tasks;  I tried both array_push($tasks, $result); and $tasks.push($result); but still the function returns Null !

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your time :)